# adb reverse doesn't work for ajax / xhr requests

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I am running a cordova app on my android device, connected via USB to my computer, on which I run the server on `http://localhost:8888`. I've also run `adb reverse tcp:8888 tcp:8888`, which allows traffic from the device to pass through to the computer.

Now, when I open a browser on my device, when I go to `http://localhost:8888/`, I can see the result. But when I do an ajax / xhr request from the cordova app, the result is 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I already limited the URLs that my cordova app can access (instead of "*"), and I therefore I needed to add this setting, after which it all works!

`<access origin="http://localhost:8888" />`